# Have any NATO countries publicly raise objections as being spied upon (by the US) in "Operation Triangulation"?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, nato, espionage

[According](https://securityaffairs.com/146954/intelligence/fsb-blames-us-intel-operation-triangulation.html) to a story sourced to the FSB

> “The Federal Security Service of the Russian Federation, together with the Federal Security Service of Russia, uncovered a reconnaissance operation by American intelligence services carried out using Apple mobile devices (USA).” reads the announcement published by FSB. “It was found that several thousand telephone sets of this brand were infected. At the same time, in addition to domestic subscribers, facts of infection of foreign numbers and subscribers using SIM cards registered with diplomatic missions and embassies in Russia, including the countries of the NATO bloc and the post-Soviet space, as well as Israel, SAR and China, were revealed.”

The Moscow-based Kaspersky Lab has dubbed it "Operation Triangulation". The security vulnerabilities at least were real, and [were](https://www.securityweek.com/apple-patches-another-kernel-flaw-exploited-in-operation-triangulation-attacks/) patched by Apple.

[Sometimes](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-24647268) when news about the US spying on NATO countries breaks out, there is some kind of official protest. Have any NATO countries acknowledged being spied upon by the US in "Operation Triangulation"?